# using Go redis client (Redigo)

Tags: go, redis

I'm using GO redis client redigo to write image to ~20 redis servers.
speed is an important factor here and I'm just sending set commands to the redis so I'm using Send and Flush without calling Receive.
after a few hours I'm getting "connection reset by peer" on the client.
I was wondering, does it have something to do with the fact that I don't call Receive?
maybe my RX queue just getting to its max capacity because I don't empty it with Receive?

Thank you.

Comment: Post your code with your connection pool/setup detailed.

Comment: @elithrar I have 1 connection per redis server with no pool. I just want to know if it's ok to flush commands to redis without calling receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An application must call Receive to clear the responses from the server and to check for errors. If the application is not pipelining commands, then it's best to call Do. Do combines Send, Flush and Receive.

If you don't care about errors, then start a goroutine to read the responses:

```
go func(c redis.Conn) {
   for c.Err() == nil {
       c.Receive()
   }
}()
```

Comment: thank you man. just one more thing, I interested in ignoring the response from the redis server in order to speed up things, also, I don't care so much about a few images getting lost due to some errors. do you know about a way to disable the redis server from replying to every commands?